# Como obter (em objeto) dados do Facebook?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook

Estou criando um *Feed* (lista de conteúdo dinâmico) com o conteúdo do mural de um grupo do Facebook. Sei que exite alguns recursos que o próprio Facebook fornece, como o *Social Plugin - Like Box*. Depois de alguns testes, vi algumas dificuldades para manusear o *CSS* do *Plugin*. Futuramente vou adaptar o *Feed* pra receber do Twitter também então gostaria de diferenciar os *posts* de cada com a logo do mesmo. Vendo que esse propósito é bem específico não só em funcionalidades, mas também entra questão do *Design* já estar pronto, achei melhor pegar apenas os objetos (acho que com JS) e com JS exibi-los no meu *Feed* que já está pronto. Alguma ideia?

[image: Feed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendo da tua pergunta, tu precisas fazer uso da API do Facebook para recolher dados e/ou a *feed* de determinado utilizador recebendo os mesmos na forma de um objecto.

Se fizeres um `HTTP Get` ao endereço `graph.facebook.com` com parametros adequados ao que pretendes e uma Token de acesso válida, vais receber de volta um objecto JSON com a informação pretendida.

Existem três tipos de dados que caem dentro daquilo a que chamados de *feed*, o que te leva a utilizar o link adequado mediante o que pretendes recolher, de forma a realizares um `HTTP Get` e recolher a informação:

- Atualizações de estado <sup>*status updates*</sup>

  ```
   http://graph.facebook.com/IdUtilizador/statuses?access_token=TokenDeAcessoValido
  ```
- Lista de itens na parede do utilizador <sup>*wall stream*</sup>

  ```
   http://graph.facebook.com/IdUtilizador/wall?access_token=TokenDeAcessoValido
  ```
- Lista de itens na home do utilizador <sup>*home feed*</sup>

  ```
   http://graph.facebook.com/IdUtilizador/home?access_token=TokenDeAcessoValido
  ```

A documentação do Facebook para este assunto pode ser [encontrada aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.

A informação recebida é um JSON que é um objecto dando assim conta do teu problema.

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/6WNms/)

Em baixo um exemplo do formato de dados que recebemos:

```
{
   "id": "220439",
   "name": "Bret Taylor",
   "first_name": "Bret",
   "last_name": "Taylor",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/btaylor",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US",
   "username": "btaylor"
}
```

A utilização é relativamente simples:

```
var endereco = "http://graph.facebook.com/btaylor";
$.getJSON(endereco, function(data) {
    var name = data["name"];
    $("#meuElemento").append("<h3>"+name+"</h3>"); 
});
```

Existem também outros exemplos de informações que pode ser recolhidas na forma de objectos. [Nesta página](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/examples/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, entre muitos estão os que referi em cima.

---

## [Facebook Query Language (FQL)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

Recorrendo a linguagem de consulta do Facebook, podes realizar consultar idênticas às de SQL e recolher os dados numa forma mais prática e sem "lixo":

Na página de [Visão Geral](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, eles tem uma série de exemplos, mas vamos pela recolha do nome como ilustrado em cima:

```
var endereco = "http://graph.facebook.com/";
var consulta = "fql?q=SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = me()";
var tokenAcesso = "&access_token=XXXX";

$.getJSON(endereco+consulta+tokenAcesso, function(data) {
    var name = data["name"];
    $("#meuElemento").append("<h3>"+name+"</h3>"); 
});
```

As consultas podem ser testadas no [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.

Comment: O que seria esse 'Token De Acesso Valido' e 'ID do Utilizador' e como consigo? Tem como me dar um exemplo de uma página pública?

Comment: Jà que eu quero exibir no feed o Mural de uma página acho que seria a Wall Stream, correto?

Comment: @PhellipeLins Podes visitar esta [página](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/) para obteres os tokens de acesso para a aplicação criada. [Aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending) também obténs mais informação útil sobre o assunto.

Comment: @PhellipeLins Já agora, convém dizer que as APPs podem ser criadas e geridas [aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/apps). Troca para a língua Portuguesa no rodapé do site se estiveres pouco à vontade com o Inglês.

Comment: @Zuuul, sabe como faço pra filtrar os posts? Queria no JSON apenas os posts feitos pela própria página.

Comment: "graph.facebook.com/_ID_/feed?access_token=_TOKEN_&user=MINHA%20PAGINA" Não funciona .-.

Comment: @PhellipeLins Só vendo quando voltar ao escritório, digo algo mais tarde.

Comment: Consegui usando o '/posts?acess_token={token}'. Agora estou sofrendo pra jogar o objeto JSON pra uma variável e usá-lo. :/

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13315/discussion-between-zuul-and-phellipe-lins)

Answer (score 0):

Você vai ter dificuldades para alterar o css do plugin porque o conteúdo vai estar dentro de um iframe.

Você via ter que utilizar a o [SDK de JavaScript do FaceBook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api)

**Lendo conteúdo de uma fanpage:**

```
FB.api('/113124472034820', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**Pegando dados do usuário:**

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**Postando conteúdo:**

```
var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    console.log('Error');
  } else {
    console.log('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```